# Data race example and data race detection example

Tags: multithreading, race-condition

I am looking for an example showing all the types of data races (e.g. not having valid locks) and the example of detection method to detect it.

If both of the examples are in source code format (programming language is not limited) that would be perfect!

BTW, is there any good data race detection tool recommended?

Answer (score 1):

You can find examples of race conditions in java under http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4

To find race condition you can record the threads for all field modifications using instrumentation. If a field is modified by more than one thread without synchronization, you have found a data race.

This is implemented in http://vmlens.com. I recommend http://vmlens.com for race condition detection in java.